# Glide 4 logging

Tags: android, android-glide

I'd like to enable glide logging to see what's going on.  I tried:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.Glide DEBUG
adb shell setprop log.tag.Engine DEBUG
```

but I don't get any additional logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if the doc is out of date, but the `setprop` didn't work for me.  I had to resort to:

```
@Override
public void applyOptions(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull GlideBuilder builder) {
    builder.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
}
```